# Why, when, and how do we use xml?

Tags: xml

I'm new in web development, so bear with me please

I know that xml is used to structure a document but not to display the data in it. Why would i need to do that? and why xml? I mean wouldn't be more easier if i just structured the document in plain text?? How can xml benefits me?

Most of the example and tutorials i saw said that xml doesn't care about the data stored rather than the structure of the data stored. However the examples mentioned elements and value for those elements why is that? Shouldn't I concerned the structure? . For example:

```
<elementName>element value</elementName>
```

I know it looks stupid question, but I really don't see how can i use xml in way that simplify my work.

Comment: Check this:- http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/training/xml-what-s-it-all-about-RZ001130477.aspx?section=2

Comment: I'm struggling to see this as a programming question in SO terms so I'm voting to close it.

Comment: FYI, `plz` is not a word.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. The reason is that you can only mark one answer accepted, so if different subquestions are best answered in separate questions, you cannot mark all of them. Thus, please create a separate StackOverflow question for each of your questions.

Comment: When creating separate questions, please make sure to include examples of "what you tried", in this case, of what you consider an alternative. For example, please add an example of a small Xml document and an example how you think you'd "structure" the same data in "plain text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would i need to do that?

Because structure makes it easier to find the data you want

> and why xml?

Because it is a robust, mature specification and lots of tools can handle it. Alternatives include JSON and YAML.

> I mean wouldn't be more easier if i just structured the document in plain text?

Plain text doesn't have structure. It is just text.

XML has a hierarchy of elements with associated data.